# tcrossprod for complex matrices

Tags: r, matrix, complex-numbers

Suppose that `A` is a complex matrix and we want to calculate the product `A%*%Conj(t(A))` as efficiently as possible. `A%*%Conj(t(A))` is a [Hermitian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) so essentially we only need to calculate the elements on the diagonal and the elements below the diagonal because the elements above the diagonal can be obtained by simply taking the complex conjugate of the values below the diagonal.

I would like to use `tcrossprod(A)`, but this gives `A%*%t(A)`. If I use `tcrossprod(A,Conj(A))`, `R` does not seem to use the special structure of the product to speed up the computation.

How could I speed up the computation of `A%*%Conj(t(A))`? Is there a command similar to `tcrossprod` that would give `A%*%Conj(t(A))`?

Any help is much appreciated!